# How do I retrieve a specific corresponding info according to who logged in on postman ? (API)

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

I developed a laravel API for flutter app. Here's my **AuthController** and the following are the function. What I want to do is that once I submit the request on postman, it will display the current info of the logged-in user. Currently, I manage to retrieved the info but it instead display the data of the first user in the table instead of the corresponding user that I logged in(in postman). How do I fix this ? Please help

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        //Check email
        $user = User::where('email', $fields['email'])->first();

        //Check password
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)) {
            $result = [];
            $result['status'] = false;
            $result['message'] = "Bad creds";

            return response()->json($result);
        } else {
            $result = [];
            $result['status'] = true;
            $result['message'] = "Login successfully";

            $data = User::first(['staff_id', 'name']);
            $result['data'] = $data;

            return response()->json($result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not used Laravel in a long time but seems to me you are always retrieving the first user from your database `$data = User::first(['staff_id', 'name']);`

Comment: @meewog Ya..how do I retrieve the data of the current users that's going to log in then ? I tried get() but instead it retrieved all the data that are in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `else` block the

```
$data = User::first(['staff_id','name']);
```

means that it will fetch the first user in your database. Instead of querying again you can use the already declared `$user` since it is the data that you are looking for.

```
$data = $user;
```

How about :

```
$data = [
    'staff_id' => $user->staff_id,
    'name' => $user->name,
];
```

Comment: I tried it..it works but it retrieve all the info instead.. how do I retrieve only the 'staff_id' and 'name'?

Comment: I edited it. Try it

Comment: sry it retrieve the correct info but instead of the logged in user info, it displays all the users that are in the table

Comment: Okay I edited it again. That's my last edit.